# Save bag on cascade using Hibernate and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have te following parent class

```
public class Parent {

    private Integer id;
    private List<Child> detail = ShrinkableLazyList.decorate(
            new ArrayList<Child>(),
            FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Child.class));
```

With it's corresponding HBM as follows:

```
<class name="Parent" table="parents">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <bag name="detail" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="parentId" not-null="true" />
        <one-to-many class="Child" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

In my JSP edit form I list this detail as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${ parent.detail }" var="child" varStatus="status">
    <tr class="detail">
        <td>
            <input name="detail[${ status.count }].id" type="hidden" value="${ child.id }">
            <input name="detail[${ status.count }].account" type="hidden" value="${ child.account.id }"><span>${ child.account }</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

But when I try to perform an `update()` on the parent object I receive the following error:

```
identifier of an instance of Child was altered from 20 to 19; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of Child was altered from 20 to 19
```

This is my DAO code

```
@Override
public void update (Parent parent) {
    hibernateTemplate.update(parent);
}
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: is there any issue with `status.count` being 1 based rather than 0 based?

Comment: Give that man a cookie! please post your comment as answer so I can give you your reward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with `status.count` being 1-based rather than 0-based which would lead to the assigned values having shifted indexes.